# d3dBuffer created with various sizes not released

Tags: memory-leaks, gpu, directx, direct3d, amd-gpu

I noticed a problem with the DirectX API (driver from AMD).
If I create a d3d buffer using `createBuffer()` with incremental sizes and release it in a for loop, the memory diagnosis tools shows that the process's private bytes size is constantly increasing. I think it might be because GPU mapped system memory is never released. Btw, the CPU heap size is stable.

1. For 1000 iterations buffer size starts at 1kb to 1000 MB
2. `CreateBuffer` using `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING`/`D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` & `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE`
3. `d3dbuffer.Release` & `d3dbuffer = nullptr`
4. `context.clearstate()` and `flush()` to synchronously release `d3dbuffer`

```cpp
for (unsigned long long totalSize = 1MB; totalSize <= 1000MB ; totalSize += 1MB)
{
    // create
    CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> pd3dBuffer;
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    {
       ZeroMemory(&bufferDesc, sizeof(bufferDesc));
       bufferDesc.ByteWidth = static_cast<UINT>(bufferSize);
       bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
       bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
       bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
       bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
       bufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;
    }
    HRESULT hr = pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, NULL, pd3dBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr)) break;
    
    //release
    pd3dBuffer.Release();
    pd3dDeviceContext->ClearState();
    pd3dDeviceContext->Flush();
}
```

Because the process memory usage keeps going up and eventually reaches my physical memory 16gb limit and crashes. This is weird as I synchronously release buffer right after creation. The process memory usage should be relatively stable.
Is there anyone could explain how does not DirectX memory management work?

Comment: Wait I'll take a look onto the docs

Comment: Are you unmapping the buffer too after mapping it?

Comment: There is no mapping un-mapping involved. just creation an synchronous deletion(not delayed).

Comment: ``CreateD3D11Buffer`` is one of your functions. You should post the code for it.

Comment: Thank chuck, updated!

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, this weird behavior was caused by the DirectX implementation. Basically Microsoft as an OS company only defines the interface/specs for DirectX APIs, 3rd party GPU vendors will have to provide their own implementations of these APIs.

Nvidia will provide one, AMD will provide one, if suddenly Qualcomm wants to support DirectX, it will have to write one as well.

The buffer allocation and release mechanism is not fully defined in the DirectX specs, therefore it is up to the vendors to provide optimal memory management algorithms. Because there is a bug in the vendor's implementation to not recycle released memory handles, the system committed memory associated with the buffer is not released which causes this bug.